# What would you use to create an interactive geometry program with python?

Tags: python, geometry, vector-graphics, interactive

What libraries/modules would you recommend for creating an interactive geometry program?
What I have found includes: [Pyglet](http://pyglet.org/), [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html), [Pycairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/), [Sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/geometry.html)

I'll illustrate the basic requirements with an example:

- Create two Point objects by clicking two locations on a canvas.
- Create two intersecting Circle objects based on those two Points.
- Detect the two circles and calculate their intersections.

I would like to work with a canvas that supports anti-aliasing.
I would also like the ability to produce(export) an image with a transparent background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a bit of experience with OpenGL I would seriously recommend pyglet. Very customizable. If you don't, get it, because in Python there doesn't really exist a game/rendering library that has a "canvas-style" interface, except, to a certain point, pygame. But pygame...

Stay away from pygame. Stay away. pygame has horrendous design, documentation, code written with it and performance.

I have no experience with the two others (or any others, for that fact). There aren't many options for this domain in Python sadly (this also is the reason why I started a project like this, but it's still too unstable and WIP). Most notably the built-in support for things like anti-aliasing, primitives and intersection calculating is non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a library for interactive geometry board using tkinter.

http://bitbucket.org/zambu/pygraph